# IntelliJ: Autocopy folder content to an IntelliJ folder

Tags: intellij-idea, jetbrains-ide, intellij-14

I have a question, which seemed easy at the beginning when I started working on it but I could not find an easy solution for it so far.
Is there a way to auto copy content from a folder to a current folder in my IntelliJ project?

Away from IntelliJ, this can be done programmatically; and I will need to add a file watcher to observe changes and apply them accordingly. Alternatively, I can create a scheduled task to do this.
However, I am inclined to avoid this as there must be an easy way to do this.

Comment: What is the scenario? Are you syncing your project's folder with a webserver/production? See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/uploading-and-downloading-files.html#34282d98

Comment: Not exactly what I am looking for. I have three different projects, and each of which has a folder that has the same content as the other projects. Updating the content in one folder should sync the other folders automatically.

Comment: @Seeker 1) Have you tried symlinks? 2) You may still try the auto deployment (to copy files to another folder on your computer). I'm not sure if it will work well when doing this auto-deployment on a specific subfolder only... (never tried such partial scenario) 3) [File Watcher](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/using-file-watchers.html) may also do the job here (a custom command/script that IDE can execute when watched files get modified). Usually works for files modified by the IDE. Can also work for external modifications but the IDE must be aware of the change.

Comment: Thank you. I will check the suggestions you provided.